# NoMethodError in Controller#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, devise, mongoid

I'm doing a simple contact-book API on Ruby-on-Rails and mongoDB and facing some problems trying to assign contacts to user.

Contact model:

```
class Contact
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :name, type: String
  field :address, type: String
  field :surname, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :phone, type: String
  field :birthday, type: Date
  field :notes, type: String

  belongs_to :user
end
```

User model (generated by devise):

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

   ...

  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And create method from ContactsController:

```
def create
    **@contact = @user.contact.new(contact_params)**

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So, the aim is to assign contact to current user and to show to current user only his contacts, unfortunately stuck on this phase. Any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In `User` you have `contacts` (plural), not `contact` (singular): see `has_many :contacts...`. That's why `@user.contact` fails. What you should have done is `@user.contacts.build`, or `contact = Contact.new` and then `@user.contacts << contact`.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference for more details.